# Airflow HDFS Sensor

Tags: airflow

Trying to get HDFSSensor working. I have set up the hdfs connection and the file is there but it keeps on poking the file and never completes

Poking for file hdfs://user/airflow/stamps/test/ds=2018-10-15/_SUCCESS

code is as below

```
hdfs_sense_open = HdfsSensor(
        task_id='hdfs_sense_open',
        filepath='hdfs://user/airflow/stamps/test/ds=2018-10-15/_SUCCESS',
        hdfs_conn_id='hdfs_leo',
        dag=dag)
```

---

Actually it works without file name in the path. I would also like to add one more point when you create hdfs connection, you need to use the hdfs port number not webhdfs port, i.e. 8020 (may be 9000 if it's localhost) but not webhdfs port like 50070

```
hdfs_sense_open = HdfsSensor(
        task_id='hdfs_sense_open',
        filepath='/user/airflow/stamps/test/ds=2018-10-15/',
        hdfs_conn_id='hdfs_leo',
        dag=dag)
```

Thank you so much both of you for trying to help me out

Comment: I haven't used this sensor before, but I'd try excluding `hdfs://` from `filepath` and just use `filepath='/user/airflow...'`. Looking at the [snakebite.client.Client.ls](https://snakebite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/client.html#snakebite.client.Client.ls) which the path is passed to in the sensor, I think it could potentially be messing up the check.

Comment: actually I needed to remove /_SUCCESS and only give path to the folder that has the file. It would have been great if I had control over the file name as well

Answer (score 1):

Try it with the `filepath` set without the protocol. Like:

```
hdfs_sense_open = HdfsSensor(
        task_id='hdfs_sense_open',
        filepath='/user/airflow/stamps/test/ds=2018-10-15/_SUCCESS',
        hdfs_conn_id='hdfs_leo',
        dag=dag)
```